# Editor suggestions with git integration

Tags: devops

Can anyone suggest choices for a modern(ish) editor or IDE (mainly for use on Linux hosts/guests) that has good Git integration and if possible some level of vi/vim keystroke compatibility available ?

I mainly work with ansible, puppet, python (including pyspark), docker, k8s and editing via sshfs would also help, as would being able to use the ssh protocol (rather than git's own protocol) for remote git repo interaction.

I am considering Atom as I believe most or all of what I want can be accomplished through addition of various modules.

Answer (score 0):

I was a big Atom user in the past but in the last few years I've moved to Visual Studio Code https://code.visualstudio.com/, the git integration is really good.
The real advantage though is the plugins, I work a lot with Puppet and the official Puppet plugin is a really good https://puppet-vscode.github.io/.
Most of the documentation I write is in markdown so having a plugin to preview markdown saves me a lot of time.
I've just recently started doing some work with Terraform and the plugin for that has made it a breeze https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform. This https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker is a great Docker plugin.
There is a stack of other plugins I use all the time to help with JSON, YAML, DOT and Ruby files and marking ToDo's in files.
I haven't used one but I'd expect there is a vim/vi, I come from a Solaris/Linux background so I was naturally very resistant to using any Microsoft products but VSC has won me over despite that prejudice.